# Парсинг с сайта, поясните

Tags: java, парсер, бот

Меня интересует такой вопрос. Когда я делаю парсинг страницы ВК, бот выдает мне информацию на специфическом языке, на котором у меня локализован ВК.
Мои вопросы:

1. Как происходит скачивание контента?
2. Что видит аналитика сайта, когда заходит парсер?
3. Что если написать бесконечны цикл, где бот будет бесконечно скачивать html-страницу? Это будет мини DNS-атака?
4. Как бот вообще заходит (как???)?
5. Делаю парсинг сайта, где есть выбор языка, как подключить прокси, чтобы он выдавал, к примеру, версию вк на English;

P.S использую Jsoup.

Comment: у меня вк на белорусском языке, он и выдает информацию на таком же.

Comment: Кстати, у вк есть сдк на жаве. Бота при помощи сдк удобнее писать, чем парсить хтмл.

Comment: Как это реализовать?

Comment: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk . Сначало вам надо зарегистрировать бота, как приложение в вк. Дальше получить токен и подключиться к вк через сдк, используя токен. Гайд по ссылке.

Comment: Еще одна идея в список реализаций на будущее)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать Jsoup вместе с прокси можно так:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(                                      
        Proxy.Type.HTTP,                                      
        InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("127.0.0.1", 8080) 
);
Document doc = Jsoup //
               .connect("http://www.example.com/") //
               .proxy(proxy) //
               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2") //
               .header("Content-Language", "en-US") //
               .get();
```

Или так:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.5.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1080");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.google.com").get();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую использовать

Comment: Кстати, где искать прокси, которые использовать? Или все подходят?

Comment: @МишаКотор покупайте прокси той страны, которая вас интересует, т.к. бесплатные прокси, как правило, низкого качестве и медленные